# I accidentally voted to close a question as a dupe of another, unrelated question. How can I re-apply that vote to another question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

1. See question on feed.
2. "I've seen this question before…"
3. `close`
4. Search for term.
5. Expand question `A` to read it.
6. "Not what I'm looking for…"
7. Change search term and press enter.
8. VTC is now applied to `A`, the wrong question.
9. Retract vote (since it's not accurate).
10. Can no longer VTC.

Comment: Flag and comment?

Comment: Vote to reopen, with a comment about the 'error'

Comment: Don't vote like that please.

Comment: Maybe http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352

Answer (score 4):

You can only vote-to-close once on a question, and also only retract such a close-vote once. After that, you'll only be a spectator in the vote-to-close activity.

My typical "hunt for duplicate" approach is to use the main site to search for a duplicate. Once found I proceed to cast the vote-to-close rather than using the search-for-duplicate feature contained within the closure procedure. It avoids mishaps like you experienced.

Reference: [Can we have the ability to retract a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167514/168244)